# Routing to a special controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, controller

I want to have a button to select a zip file, unzip, process one of those files and add the data to the database. I'm stuck at getting to the controller action.

bp_stats.controller

```
def import_data
  puts "Massage and import data here"
end
```

routes.rb

```
get 'import_data', to: 'bp_stats#import_data'
```

The import button in `_import_data.html.erb`:

```
<%= form_tag( action: :import_data, controller: 'bp_stats' ) do %>
  <%= file_field_tag :filename %>
  <%= submit_tag( "Import" ) %>
<% end %>
```

I'm getting this error

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/import_data"):
```

Comment: I would suggest understanding what the rake task is doing, which methods are called in which order and then calling it in the same order in your controller.

Comment: @HarshKumar. Thank you answering. I can't get routes straightened out. I updated original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route says

```
get 'import_data', to: 'bp_stats#import_data'
```

which is clearly a get request route not a post request, you need to change this to a route for a post request using post

```
post 'import_data', to: 'bp_stats#import_data'
```

Comment: Thank you. Obvious from the error, but I'm a bit in the woods. Now on to sorting out the processing of the imported data which I can do with a Rake task. Unless this isn't the way to go about it.

Comment: @Greg rake task run as a background job is the way to go

Comment: And that can be triggered by the controlle?

Comment: @Greg take a look at delayed_job, worker queues etc... Your controller action could call a model method to add the job to a queue, and delayed job can beaver away in the background picking off jobs and working away thus returning the user back to the  website with no delay. A place to start might be to google railscasts delayed_job., it's very old but it'll give you the idea

Comment: Thanks. Ill do that. I've already used an old Railscasts for this tiny app

Comment: In looking at it, I realized that my task is for users to import and see their data, so they need to wait. I found out how to run the import task, so added `system "rails import:blood_stats"` and `redirect_to blood_stats_url` to the controller. Need to add a progress indicator, but at this point it's fast enough, but might take longer as more data is added. This is daily readings and all of them need to be run through. If this works out, will have to fix that in the future. Thanks for the suggestions. I may be back, I'm not picking up the filename yet.

Comment: @Greg, that is not going to stop a timeout error in production if the browser has to wait too long. You should NEVER keep a user waiting. You can use other tools to show progress of a job but you need to return a response back to the browser after a request ASAP always. So you could maybe use some of the new rails features to help with this and maybe `ActionCable` is a good fit here. Set up some listening events in the page that the browser redirects to as soon as you have passed off the work to the background job, you could then maybe fire off updates to whatever channels are listening

Comment: @Greg https://www.learnenough.com/action-cable-tutorial might be a good place to start but there are possibly better resources out there now it has matured somewhat, you could maybe update the channel with each line as it is processed, that way the user would see data magically being inserted into their redirected web page as they watch

Comment: Thank you for important heads up. Guess I'm diving in even deeper. Update: Ruby & Copeland: Agile Web Development has a few pages on Action Cable/WebSockets that's close to my case.